# REST API with 1000 query templates?

Tags: rest, golang

How do I manage maybe 1000 SQL-queries in a Golang REST API?

My SQL experience is at the upper basic level using Postgresql. I am today using a tool that you can use plain SQL as well as sort of ORM to direct access the database. The aim of using ORM is to make simpler, but with complex queries it really makes it harder. So I prefer using plain SQL and want to avoid GORM or similar.

When it comes to Golang, my experience is at the early beginners level. I have done a simple REST API with about 5 queries. And it is manageable.

All Golang REST API examples are at the Hello World level. But I need a way to handle several hundreds structs and queries. Easy to code and easy to understand and maintain. And I have so far found 3 ways to do this.

1. Store the queries using templates or similar.
   https://github.com/gchaincl/dotsql
2. Use 1000 packages. But this seems to be unmanageable to me.
3. Store the queries together with the struct in a lookup Postgresql database. Fetch the desired query and fire the query. This will be easy to maintain, but adds another layer that may impact speed.

Besides these thoughts, I have tried a dynamic approach with no luck.

I wonder if anyone that run into this can share some thoughts and advises?

TIA!

Comment: `The aim of using ORM is to make simpler, but with complex queries, it really makes it harder.` Not really, the idea is to avoid having to hardcode thousand static queries or convoluted dynamic queries via built upon string concatenations. The more SQL you need the more useful is the ORM. Anyways, you could implement an ORM for the bulk of the queries and do use query templates for the complex ones. Overall if those require some degree of efficiency. Things few times are all black or all white. Sometimes grey is the color you need.

Comment: whats wrong with hardcoding the sql?

Comment: @Ewan Depends on the needs for OP's to add new structures (and hence new queries), the frequency it happens, etc. In other words, economy of scale. If hardcoding thousands of queries and deploy thousands more is cheaper than implementing a dynamic approach, then there should be no problem (apparently). If technically both fulfil the needs, then it's a matter of business strategy. IMO.

Comment: @laiv looks like in all their approaches the sql is stored somewhere rather than being dynamically generated.

Comment: I think OP still has no solution. He's still in design phase. ATM, storing queries somewhere is just one option over the table.

Comment: @laiv "The more SQL you need the more useful is the ORM. Anyways, you could implement an ORM for the bulk of the queries and do use query templates for the complex ones." How about CTE, UNIONs and subqueries? It seems to me be way harder using ORM. Just my experience from one type of ORM...

Comment: I would not use ORM to solve queries with a certain degree of complexity. That's why I suggest using both approaches. ORM for the bulk (mainly CRUD queries) and complex ones with SQL templates. Unions, subqueries, and some joins would be out of my idea of "simple queries for CRUD".

Comment: $Laiv "Unions, subqueries, and some joins" is about 90 percent (the bulk) of my queries. Which means that ORM is not the holy grail for me. But I admit it is tempting to use ORM at a first glance. Some said that the CUD part may be suitable for ORM, but not the R part...

Comment: What would writing in 1000 package enable you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write 1000 packages.

The benefit of doing it this way is that you make best use of your existing source control and deployment pipeline to manage the sql.

Storing the queries somewhere else means you need to implement extra change control around that storage.

The real question here though is why do you have 1000 sql queries? Maybe you simply have 1000 tables, or say 250 with CRUD on each.

But perhaps there is some other flaw in your design or requirments which is cauing you to have more logic in your SQL than required.

For instance, if I had an API getEmployees in company, I wouldnt add a getEmployeeByCompanyAndEmployeeName unless there were 1000's of employees per company. I would let the calling code do that search.

Similarly I would only select and return all the fields in a table, rather than having sql for different subsets of the data. Its the calling codes job to decide which fields it uses or not.

You really have to have something different to a standard 'hide the database' api to want to make the sql editiable separately from the code.

Comment: Do I have to import 1000 packages at main.go in order to use packages?

Comment: yes, but one might assume that you would have more than one sql statement in a package. eg selectCustomerById .. ByName.. ByCompany... etc

Comment: Could I use the same package for all CRUDs? POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE and PUT? In order to reduce number of packages?

Comment: you could, but i would not worry about the number of packages. put stuff together if it belongs together

Comment: What is the benefits with packages compared with https://github.com/gchaincl/dotsql ?

Comment: with that package you will have to deploy your sql files and ensure the app can read them. all you save is a couole of lines of code. I would not use it.